# Can you set an array of dates as a constant in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm not even sure if this can be done, but if I want to make a function that figures out some business time things, and I want to have a constant that represents holidays, can I do something like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION businesstime(start_time, end_time)
...
DECLARE
  HOLIDAYS constant date[] := '{2019-01-01, 2019-07-04, 2019-11-28}'
BEGIN
  -- do business time stuff with holidays
END
...
```

If so, how? I can't get past syntax errors and I'm not sure if it's because I'm doing it wrong or it's impossible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon in your example is missing.

This code is working on my computer:

```
do $$
declare d date[] default '{2017-01-01, 2018-01-01}';
begin
  raise notice '%', d;
end;
$$;
```

there are four different syntaxes, but the result and performance will be almost same (maybe there can be very small performance differences that depends on usage):

```
-- string literal of unknown type with late implicit casting
d := '{2017-01-01, 2018-01-01}';

-- string literal of date[] type 
d := _date '{2017-01-01, 2018-01-01}';
```

There is little bit hack - for date array type I have to use alternative type name `_date`. It is old convention - internal names of array types starts by prefix `_`.

```
-- string literal of unknown type with immediate explicit casting
d := '{2017-01-01, 2018-01-01}'::date[];
d := CAST('{2017-01-01, 2018-01-01}' AS date[]);

-- using array constructor with late implicit casting
d := ARRAY['2017-01-01', '2018-01-01'];

-- using array constructor with casting of array
d := ARRAY['2017-01-01', '2018-01-01']::date[];

-- using array constructor with immediate casting of field
d := ARRAY['2017-01-01'::date, '2018-01-01'];
```

Type of first element forces types of other elements of array

There are more ways how to write array constant - but the differences between mentioned ways are for almost use cases almost zero.

Comment: Cool, this is super useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Welp, finally got it. Just needed to cast:

```
HOLIDAYS constant date[] := '{2019-01-01, 2019-07-04, 2019-11-28}'::date[]
```

Still not sure if this is the best way to do it though, so not going to accept my own answer just yet. Would love to know if this is really the best/only way.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it is very simple to do this in PostgreSQL just with using `generate_series` and `array_agg` functions, as below is the PL/PGSQL function definition and the example to use:

```
create or replace function generate_series_dates(varchar, varchar) returns date[] 
As
'with series_dates as (
    select generate_series($1::date, $2::date, ''1 days''::interval)::date as date
  )
  select array_agg(date) from series_dates'
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;
CREATE FUNCTION

select generate_series_dates('2018-01-01','2018-01-05');
                  generate_series_dates                   
----------------------------------------------------------
 {2018-01-01,2018-01-02,2018-01-03,2018-01-04,2018-01-05}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, but I wasn't looking to get a series, just to assign the array of known dates (not passed as args) to a constant before doing other work with the data.